# In localhost node app is running fine but after pushing in CF and registered in Mindsphere pages showing 404 status

Tags: cloud-foundry, mindsphere

Im new to Cloud Foundry and Mindsphere. My node application is running good in the local host.

After uploading to Cloud Foundry and registered in mindsphere. The files are not loading. Even the CSS file also showing the 404 Status(in the network).

How can load all files?Whats Wrong i'm doing here?

The following is my Localhost (loading files):

[image: Localhost network files]

The following is After I upload and registered URL:

[image: Cloud newwork files]

Thanks in advance

Comment: This appears to be the same question. Responding over there. [React app is working fine in localhost But when i upload in Cloud Foundry and registered in Mindsphere 404 not found:error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61017871/react-app-is-working-fine-in-localhost-but-when-i-upload-in-cloud-foundry-and-re)

Comment: looks same but tech difference..but here at least loading the html(this app is with node & html).There Not at all loading the document(that is Reactjs app).

Comment: Weird question, but what does the 404 response look like? That can tell you what is returning the 404. Gorouter or your app. Alternatively, look at `cf logs` for your app and see if you get a 404 `[RTR]` log entry.

Comment: @DanielMikusa One of the docs i recently read that CF supports only few buildpacks. React is not one of it. I this is because of that. Or React Comens under NodeJS also?

Comment: You don't need a React.js buildpack. There is nothing that needs to be installed, it's just static files that get served up by any number of web servers. The easiest way is to use the staticfile_buildpack to serve up your files. Is that what you are using?

Comment: @DanielMikusa i tried with react buildpack also, Hope you remember the 1st comment.With react , document also not loading