# React app is working fine in localhost But when i upload in Cloud Foundry and registered in Mindsphere 404 not found:error

Tags: cloud-foundry, mindsphere

I'm new to Cloudfoundry and Mindsphere.When running React app(simple app) in local is working fine. But when push to Cloud Foundry and registered in mindsphere, While accessing the URL, it showing the the following error:

> 404 Not Found: Requested route ('demo-react-app.xxxxxx.xxxx1.mindsphere.io') does not exist.

Document(page) itself is not loading.

please help,How to rectify this error?

[image]

Comment: The error is saying that the route you're requesting doesn't exist or the app to which this route is mapped is not running. Run `cf app <name>` to get the status & list of routes bound to your app. If you don't have a route bound, run `cf map-route` to add one. If the app isn't running, run `cf logs --recent <app>` to get the logs & investigate why. If you need more help, include your app logs & also the full `cf push` command you're running.

Comment: I'll try and update. Thanks @DanielMikusa